# How to translate the content with Symfony?

Tags: symfony, language-translation

I try to translate dates in French. I succeeded to have the right format, but the month is in English.

I have this in config/packages/translation.yaml :

```
framework:
    default_locale: fr
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - fr
```

And I created forms.fr.yaml
in translations fold :

```
Jan: Janvier
Feb: Février
Mar: Mars
Apr: Avril
May: Mai
Jun: Juin
Jul: Juillet
Aug: Août
Sep: Septembre
Oct: Octobre
Nov: Novembre
Dec: Décembre
```

At the moment, it doesn't work. What did I miss ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using format_datetime filter? it should be automatically localized. https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/28-intl.html#localizing-dates

Comment: Yes. I had this error : The "format_datetime" filter is part of the IntlExtension, which is not installed/enabled; try running "composer require twig/intl-extra" in "security/login.html.twig".

Comment: I also tried to run "composer require twig/intl-extra" but it didn't work.

Comment: Where and how do you use this translations? In a choice-field of a form ?

Comment: Hello V-Light. Yes, at the beginning I did it to help me to translate months in the choice-field of my form. But then, I set default_locale: fr in translation.yalm and it worked.

Comment: Now, I am trying to display date that is saved in database in my language. With this expression 'd M y', I can read 1 May 1989 instead of 1 Mai 1989.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format_date` adn/or `format_datetime` filter from twig

Like

```
{{ '2019-08-07 23:39:12'|format_datetime('full', 'full', locale='fr') }}
{# or #}
{{ myDateVariable|format_datetime('short', 'short') }}
{# or #}
{{ date('now')|format_date('medium', locale='de')
```

Take a look at the docs https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/format_datetime.html

You can specify your own format-pattern.

Note: In order to use it, you'll need `twig/intl-extra` and `twig/extra-bundle`

Comment: Hello V-Light ! I have an error : The "format_datetime" filter is part of the IntlExtension, which is not installed/enabled; try running "composer require twig/intl-extra" in "security/login.html.twig". The problem is when I run composer require symfony/intl in Terminal, I have this error : Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: @EmilieTossan try to run composer command in verbose mode.
`composer require twig/intl-extra twig/extra-bundle -vv`. Composer just don't stop without letting you know what was happened. You need to look carefully to the error-message.

Comment: Thank you V-light. Your answer was useful, as always. :) I paid attention to my errors : I downgraded my composer to version 1.x then, I switched back to composer version 2.x. The installation succeded. :D